# how to change input size to match inception v3 in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to run a pretrained pytorch InceptionV3 model on my own data.
The data size is (N,N).
The batch size is 128.

InceptionV3 requires (batch_size, 3, 229, 229) as input.

I tried to resize using the torch.transforms Resize function:

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((229, 229)),
                                       transforms.ToTensor()])
```

which did not work.

I also tried

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((3, 229, 229)),
                                       transforms.ToTensor()])
```

which also didn't work.

I'm already defining the batch size using a dataloader:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128)
```

Also saw a suggestion here, but I do not understand how this number of neurons is calculated.
https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `299` is for evaluation, for training you need bigger size(due to aux classifiers)

```
from torchvision import models
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torch import nn

model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
w = 299
inputs = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(512, 512, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(inputs)
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((w, w)),
                                        transforms.ToTensor()])

inputs = train_transforms(img)
print(inputs.shape)
model(inputs[None, ...])[0].shape
```

So in training, use bigger size for example 350

```
from torchvision import models
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torch import nn

model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
w = 350
inputs = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(512, 512, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(inputs)
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((w, w)),
                                       transforms.ToTensor()])

inputs = train_transforms(img)
print(inputs.shape)
model(inputs[None, ...])[0].shape
```

Comment: does this also work if our original image size is less than 229, instead of 512 in ur example?

Comment: Yes, because there is `Resize((w, w))`, which resize the image shape to `350`, as `w` was set in the code to `350`